# JSF 2 login implementation

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, faces-config

i'm trying to implement a very basic (at this point) login screen with JSF 2 (using NetBeans).  i've found several examples, from which i copied the source code, but so far unsuccessfully. 
in my login.xhtml file i have a 2 input fields and a command button -

```
<h:commandButton value="go!" actionListener="#{LoginBean.CheckValidUser}" />
```

in my LoginBean, the validation function looks like this -

```
public String CheckValidUser() { 
    if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin")){ 
        return "welcome"; 
    } 
    else{ 
       return "fail";
    } 
}
```

and to my faces-config.xml i've added the following navigation rule:

```
<navigation-rule>
    <description>login success</description>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{LoginBean.CheckValidUser}</from-action> 
        <from-outcome>welcome</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect/>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

anyhow - i just won't work, i enter the correct UN and PW but i don't get to 'welcome.xhmtl'.  when i debug the code, i see in the validation function it works as expected, but i can i know that the faces-config.xml is configured correctly?

what did i miss?
cheers, 
eRez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here,

```
<h:commandButton value="go!" actionListener="#{LoginBean.CheckValidUser}" />
```

You should be using `action` instead of `actionListener`. Fix it accordingly:

```
<h:commandButton value="go!" action="#{LoginBean.CheckValidUser}" />
```

Action listeners are supposed to return `void` and they are not intented to navigate.

#### See also:

- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, remove the `<navigation-rule>` altogether. It's unnecessary since JSF 2.0 with the new *Implicit Navigation* support. An outcome of `"welcome"` will implicitly go to `"welcome.xhtml"` already. Make sure that you're reading JSF 2.x targeted resources/books/tutorials and not JSF 1.x ones. JSF 2.x is a major change as compared to JSF 1.x.

#### See also:

- [Our JSF tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)

Comment: thanks!  believe me that on each search for information i make - it begins with 'jsf 2', but the web page i find aren't always clear about which version they use.